# What is the grammar of ~they end up being broken’

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

> that a person must handle the unbroken (drinking) glasses on display
>   with care because otherwise they may end up being broken.

In the above sentence, I don’t know why it has used *they may end up being broken* I have difficulty with *end up being broken*? Why *being* or *being broken*?

Comment: The sentence makes perfect sense. 'Being broken' is the passive voice of the verb 'broke'. It means the action of breaking was happening to the glasses, not that the glasses were performing the action of breaking.

Comment: Check [*end up*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/end-up). The end result is usually unexpected or unwanted. Of course they don't want their glasses broken.

Answer (score 1):

As @user3169 said, I think the part of the sentence that is confusing to you is 'end up', which is a somewhat idiomatic 'verbal phrase' in English usually used in the context of accidental results.

Because 'end up' behaves like a verb, it needs to take a (in this case passive) present participle 'being broken'.

'Being broken (by someone)' is the passive form of the active participle 'breaking'. You could put it in the active form of 'they may end up breaking'.

You could also get rid of 'end up' entirely and say

> 'that a person must handle the unbroken (drinking) glasses on display with care because otherwise they may break/be broken.'

Without the verbal phrase 'end up' the verb 'break' behaves like a 'normal' active or passive verb, and not a present participle.