# end up + (being) + adjective

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, ellipsis

> 1-  If he carries on driving like that, he'll end up ***dead***.
>   ([Source](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/end-up))
>
> 2- The last time he was in the room with a serial killer, he ended up
>   ***chained*** to a hospital bed.

(It is from a tv-series. He was in a room with a serial killer as a result he had a panic attack then in the hospital they chained him to a bed because he was still having some episodes after the incident.)

Is using "being" before the adjective/past participle here optional?

> 1a-  If he carries on driving like that, he'll end up ***being
>   dead***.
>
> 2a-  The last time he was in the room with a serial killer, he ended
>   up ***being chained*** to a hospital bed

Answer (score 1):

- **end up dead** is fine. No, **being** is not needed and is not really grammatical here.
- end up + adjective (dead, alive, rich, poor, sick, ill, crazy, etc;.) 
  Those are adjectives that describe a person's state or condition.

Please note the verbal phrases:
- end up **being a nice person** = verbal phrase
- end up **getting rich** [idiom]
- end up **getting home** [get home, idiom with get: get here, get there, get to school]
- end up **understanding the plot**
- end up **dropping out of school**

When there is a verbal phrase, you need an ing. If it is simply an adjective that works for end up, you do not.

Comment: But I just saw a sentence that uses "being" before "past participle" . That is why created this issue.  "That a person must handle the unbroken (drinking) glasses on display with care because otherwise they may end up ***being broken***. "(https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/187869/what-is-the-grammar-of-they-end-up-being-broken) . Even in sentence 2, is "being" unnecessary?

Comment: **being broken [by someone] is a passive form**. "being dead" in your sample sentence is not. **The glasses are being broken by the boys in the cafeteria**. That use of being broken has zero to do with end up.